# Cannot respond with XML in spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

We current have a Spring App that responds with json. We are attempting to support xml responses as well. Currently, the controller method looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = URIConstants.POSTS, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public @ResponseBody RestResponse<PostResponse> getItems(@RequestBody Request request, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) throws Exception {

  // do stuff
}
```

We added the below to our server config xml:

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
         class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And here is the full config file:

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
         class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="spurJSONMapper"  class="com.ct.app.utilities.SpurJSONMapper"/>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <ref bean="interceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="interceptor" 
            class="com.ct.app.controller.RequestInterceptor">
</bean>


  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMapping HandlerAdapter">
   <property name="messageConverters">
      <list>
          <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>

      </list>
   </property>
</bean>


<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
 </bean>
```

When we request the resource we get this in response: "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method."

Not sure where the hole is in the config, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to read and write XML, you will need to configure the `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` with a specific `Marshaller` and an `Unmarshaller` implementation from the `org.springframework.oxm` package.

Update your XML to consider below

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <util:list id="beanList">
            <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </util:list>
    </property
</bean>

<bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>

<bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller"/>
```

So, your updated config should look like (*I quickly updated, so please double check once*)

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
         class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="spurJSONMapper"  class="com.ct.app.utilities.SpurJSONMapper"/>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <ref bean="interceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="interceptor" 
            class="com.ct.app.controller.RequestInterceptor">
</bean>


  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
   <property name="messageConverters">
      <list>
          <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
          <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"/>
          <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter"/>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>

<bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>

<bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller"/>

<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
 </bean>
```

Read more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

On a side note, for `CastorMarshaller` you must have `spring-oxm-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar` JAR, which I guess you already should be having.

Comment: Thanks! This got my 99% of the way there. I also had to add annotations to all of my classes so they could be converted to xml.